# On a Tor status page what do these columns stand for?

Tags: relays, stats

There is [a Tor status web page](https://torstatus.blutmagie.de/) (**warning: it loads pretty slowly**), probably unofficial, which I usually use to see what is going on with a certain node.

The page has the following fields for each tor-relay: Router Name; Bandwidth   (KB/s); Uptime; Hostname; ORPort; DirPort; Bad Exit; FirstSeen; ASName; ASNumber; ConsensusBandwidth KB/s; OrAddress

The meaning of most of these fields are clear. But what do the **ASName**, **ASNumber**, **ConsensusBandwidth** KB/s, **OrAddress** mean?

And how the **ConsensusBandwith** is different from the **Bandwidth**?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AS Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_%28Internet%29)

> Within the Internet, an autonomous system (AS) is a collection of connected Internet Protocol (IP) routing prefixes under the control of one or more network operators on behalf of a single administrative entity or domain that presents a common, clearly defined routing policy to the Internet.

[Consensus Weight](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt#n2687)

> Weight assigned to this relay by the directory authorities that clients use in their path selection algorithm.

[OR Address](https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en#ORPort)

> The IPv4 or IPv6 address associated with a port that the relay is listening on to talk to other Tor relays or clients.

As for why bandwidth and consensus bandwidth differ, one of them it a claim the relay makes pf itself and the other is what directory authorities are able to record.

You should instead use [Atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org/), which uses [Onionoo](https://onionoo.torproject.org/) which actually [explains some of these terms](https://onionoo.torproject.org/protocol.html#details)